# Hyphen between page number gets (blured/diluted) in reference when viewing

Tags: xetex, symbols, pdftex, luatex, dvipdfmx

Title says this weird problem. The hyphen in the end, between the page number `770-808`, gets blurred and diluted. (In this case, if I select and paste in somewhere else, `770808` will show and the hyphen will disappear, but in pic 2&3 cases, I select and paste, then I get `770-808`, hyphen still there)

I am using Win7 Ultra 64bit, and the latest Adobe Reader 11.0.06

See picture 1 to 4, as I viewed my work in 4 different formats (by LyX 2.07), problem occurs in pdflatex (pic 1) and LuaTeX (pic 4), but the hyphen displays normally in XeTeX (Pic 3) and divpdfm (pic 2).

So weird, the difference between XeTeX and pdflatex is some Unicode support, right?(I’m new, maybe I’m wrong.) I want to let pdflatex also display normally like XeTeX and divpdfm (pic 2 and 3), how do I fix it?

[image: pdflatex]

[image: dvipdfm]

[image: XeTex]

[image: LuaTex]

btw: The hyphen in context part is displayed perfectly, problems only occurs in reference.
Also, it is not `bst` file fault, since I changed several `bst`, problem is still there and not `bib` fault, I am using `pages = {770--808}`.

Comment: This is not an answer really but you probably want to use `--` for ranges such as page numbers as it is typographically correct. Otherwise, please post a Minimum Working Example which people can compile to reproduce the problem. It is hard to help when nobody has any idea what you code looks like except you. Depending on what you are using for referencing, the rangedash may be what is disappearing anyway so you might want to check that...

Comment: you say you're cutting and pasting.  it's quite possible that whatever you're cutting and pasting *from* has had the en-dash (it's not a hyphen) turned into a unicode character, which is not necessarily recognized in tex input.  the comment that you should use `--` is a reliable approach.